# Traduction de « snowflake complaint »

Tags: traduction, anglais, anglicismes

[image]

L'expression « snowflake complaint » est associé à une situation qui pourrait avoir des connotations racistes, et on pourra se faire une idée de cela dans cet [article du Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/apr/11/essex-pub-landlady-benice-ryley-replaces-golliwog-doll-collection-that-was-seized-by-police), d'où la photographie est tirée (l'expression ne se trouve pas dans le texte).

Il existe un terme courant, « snowflake generation », qui assez souvent est traduit en français par « snowflake generation » ou « génération snowflake » ou « génération flocon de neige » ([Translators Cafe](https://www.translatorscafe.com/cafe/MegaBBS/forumthread30045.htm))

Est-ce qu'on peut traduire par « récrimination snowflake » ou « récrimination flocon de neige », ou bien est-ce qu'un autre terme existe qui serait préférable ? On trouve dans les possibilités offertes dans le site « [Translators Cafe](https://www.translatorscafe.com/cafe/MegaBBS/forumthread30045.htm) » le terme « sensiblerie ».

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sensiblerie)) Péj. Sensibilité outrée et fausse; compassion ridicule et déplacée.

*recherche sur la signification de « snowflake » (suscitée par [nouvelle réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/53469/17649))*

[URBAN dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Snowflake)  Snowflakes can be liberal or conservative. Whether it is a compliment or an insult is a matter of opinion and depends on the context.

[Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/snowflake) 5. (Argot) (États-Unis) (Politique) Quelqu'un qui croit qu'il est unique ; quelqu'un de très sensible aux insultes, en particulier des jeunes politiquement correct.

[Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/snowflake) 6. (Missouri) (Années 1860) Quelqu'un (généralement un Blanc) opposé à l'abolition de l'esclavage.

[Cambridge Dictionnary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/snowflake)  noun [C] (PERSON)
informal disapproving
1- an insulting way of referring to someone who is considered by some people to be too easily upset and offended:
• Why are young liberals known as snowflakes?
2- US, informal disapproving
an insulting word for a gay person:
• Once again, a Facebook troll called me a snowflake.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snowflake)) 3 informal + usually disparaging
a: someone regarded or treated as unique or special
b: someone who is overly sensitive

Answer (score 3):

Pour ce qui est de l'expression "snowflake complaint" en général, elle est trop dépendante d'une culture anglo-saxonne actuelle et spécifique (à rapprocher du problème des "Karen" aux USA), pour qu'une traduction couvre parfaitement la combinaison complexe des connotations impliquées: sens exagéré de sa propre importance, fragilité devant toute remise en cause de ses opinions, narcissisme mais aussi position politique libérale - l'expression est utilisée par la droite (américaine, britannique) pour critiquer voire insulter la gauche (dans le contexte "culture wars", "woke", "cancel culture", "BLM", etc etc).

Tout cela va être très difficile à maintenir dans une traduction: les références culturelles n'existent pas, ou sont d'importation extrêmement récente et sans correspondance véritable dans un contexte français (de France), à mon avis. L'expression est ancrée dans un ensemble de problématiques sociologiques et un contexte politique qui n'existent pas de façon "native" en France, ou pas de la même façon (et je suis très conscient que la francophonie ne se réduit pas du tout à la France!).

*Récrimination snowflake* et *récrimination flocon de neige* à mon avis ne passent pas du tout, soit à cause du mot anglais "snowflake" qui cantonne l'expression à un certain segment "branché" de la population, soit parce que la traduction directe "flocon de neige" est simplement bizarre dans cette expression en français - on ne comprend pas ce que la neige vient faire là-dedans.

*Sensiblerie* ou bien *sensiblerie ridicule/exagérée/mal placée* ou encore *bien-pensant* sont peut-être les meilleures approximations, mais ne sont pas une traduction "parfaite" non plus car le contexte "Karen" et toutes les implications ci-dessus ne passent pas forcément dans ces expressions.

Tout bien considéré, "because of some snowflake complaint" pourrait être traduit (en général, et sans essayer d'importer toutes les connotations) par:

> en raison d'une plainte d'une sensiblerie exagérée/bien pensante

Comment: Le texte me fait penser à certaines insultes racistes comne "Blanche Neige" en Français ou "black face" en Anglais.

Comment: @Graffito Oui, mais "snowflake generation/complaint" fait partie du contexte actuel des "culture wars" dans le monde anglo-saxon, peut-être originaire d'abord des US, qui s'exportent tout doucement, mais qui ne correspondent pas à des problématiques françaises (de France) à mon avis. C'est très chargé politiquement aux US, mais on n'a pas les mêmes référents en France pour ces problématiques sociologiques/politiques éminnement américaines.

Comment: On en apprend tous les jours. Si je comprends bien, c'est entre "immature" et "politiquement correct".

Comment: @Graffito C'est super dur à traduire, vu toutes les connotations... pour bien comprendre, il faut suivre les événements de la politique contemporaine aux US (ce que je ne recommande absolument pas! :-/ ). Mais oui, il y a des éléments d'immaturité et de "politiquement correct", entre autres.

Comment: Les problématique françaises sont bien présentes et ne datent pas d'hier (« Ya bon Banania », très similaire pour un contexte raciste). Il reste à savoir si ce vocabulaire y est associé, et conjointement s'il existe des courants sociaux dans lesquels il aurait du succès.

Comment: Ma réponse est négative: les connotations et référents sont trop dissimilaires et même si la connotation raciste est probablement présente dans le contexte de ce pub en Angleterre (quoi que cela soit un peu surprenant pour moi), je ne pense pas **qu'en général**, "snowflake" ait nécessairement cette connotation raciste. De plus, la combinaison de référents présents à l'origine aux US dans _snowflake_ ne correspond à rien en France - du moins c'est mon point de vue.

Comment: Une difficulté supplémentaire à mon avis est que les "culture wars" américaines essaient de s'exporter, on en retrouve certains éléments en Australie, en Angleterre, plutôt dans le monde anglo-saxon en raison de la langue, mais pas seulement. J'ai l'impression qu'en Europe, cette exportation est encore très limitée - on trouvera donc peut-être (je spécule) "flocon de neige" dans des cercles très limités, comme une tentative d'importation de la problématique US correspondante, avec des résonances artificielles. Ou bien l'expression réussira mieux au Québec, plus proche des US.

Comment: "Bien pensant" n'est pas utilisé que pour parler de la droite, au contraire. Je pense que le terme "sensiblerie bien-pensante" convient bien et est attesté sur le web

Comment: @qoba J'ai ajouté à ma réponse. Merci.

Comment: _Snowflake_ n'est pas raciste mais simplement méprisant, comme l'emploi que les gens qui utilisent ça font de _woke_. Un flocon de neige, ce n'est pas ferme et c'est unique. L'effet est une forme d'assimilation à la pleurnicherie qui a pour but de diffamer les gens qui ont ces valeurs et qui les affirment. Incidemment j'y perçois des relents d'homophobie et de misogynie.

Comment: @s.H.a.R.p.R.i.F.t Je suis d'accord: _snowflake_ renvoit à _prima donna_, _entitled_, se sentir unique (et précieux) comme un petit cristal de flocon de neige tout joli et minutieux, mais pas a priori d'idée de racisme.

Answer (score 3):

Je dirais

> La police les a saisis ce matin parce que de petits fragiles se sont plaints

Cf Merriam Webster, [snowflake](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snowflake) 3.b.

> Someone who is overly sensitive
>
> *One side derides the youth driving the movement as snowflakes and social justice warriors, too sensitive and too politically correct.*—
> Vanessa McCray
>
> *We are not delicate creatures. We are not snowflakes.*—
> Rosie DiManno

(N.B. : je ne partage pas le point de vue qui accompagne généralement cette expression, mais je ne pense pas que la phrase même mérite une sur-traduction dans un sens explicitement raciste. Le contexte : phrase précédente, photo, article, actualité récente ou moins... fait ensuite bien sûr le reste pour se forger une opinion.)

Answer (score 2):

> Désolé mais il n'y a plus les affiches *Y'a bon, Banania*. Elle ont été saisies par la police ce matin parce qu'une chochotte a rouspété !!!

Le Robert

> [Définition de **chochotte**](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/chochotte)​​​ : adjectif et nom féminin
> familier **Qui est maniéré, prétentieux.**
> – **Qui est d'une sensibilité exagérée.**
> – **nom féminin** *Quelle chochotte, ce type !*

Comment: Une traduction précise du terme « snowflake » en tant que terme non politique ; vu le manque de contexte en ce qui concerne le point de vue des propriétaires et vu la grande proximité de sens du terme politique on devrait pouvoir se contenter de « chochotte » dans le présent contexte.

Comment: Le point de vue des propriétaires ne fait guère de doute. Le mari a été vu avec un tee-shirt de [Britain's First](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Britain_First) (mouvement ouvertement fasciste) et la réponse de la propriétaire du pub ressemble à du foutage de gueule: *She confirmed that her husband had been photographed in a T-shirt from the far-right group Britain First. She said: “I don’t think Chris is a supporter of Britain First, he was just wearing that shirt because it was convenient at the time.”*

Comment: Dans ce cas est-ce qu'on peut dire que l'« accusation » politique qui devrait se trouver dans « snowflake » soit  vraiment rendue par « chochotte » ?

Comment: Oui, je trouve que cette expression pourrait être utilisée par le même style de personnes. Par exemple, Eric Zemmour dit en 2021 que les républicains *jouaient les chochottes*.

Comment: https://www.gala.fr/l_actu/news_de_stars/des-chochottes-eric-zemmour-clashe-les-republicains-sans-menagement_477243 Je crois plutôt qu'il voulais dire que la réunion de la droite ne pourrait pas se faire si les divers groupes  s'arrêtaient à des détails.

Answer (score 1):

Une comparaison est utile à la traduction. On peut imaginer une situation aux États-Unis où un propriétaire de bar y affiche un drapeau « confédéré » tout en affirmant ne pas être raciste. Ce genre d'insouciance et d'ignorance serait difficilement conciliable avec l'idée que n'importe quelle personne qui décide d'entrer dans l'établissement s'y sente la bienvenue.

> In another post, Chris Ryley wrote: 'They used to hang them in
> Mississippi years ago' alongside a picture of the dolls hanging from
> his bar.
>
> 'It was a tongue in cheek remark, but I was just expressing a
> historical fact. I wasn't trying to offend anyone. [yet succeeding at it, NDLR]
>
> Others include a post asking: 'When is White History Month please.
> Anybody know?' while in another a golliwog is pictured with the
> caption: 'Hello Great Britain Am I Allowed Back In?'
>
> Referring to his 'White Lives Matter' post from June 2020 he said:
> 'Everybody was going on about Black Lives Matter and to be honest, I
> was getting sick of it. Nobody seemed to care about other lives.
>
> 'I don't care if you're black, brown or white because to me, all lives
> matter. That was the point that I was trying to make. And I would like
> to know when white history month is because we also have a history to
> celebrate.'
>
> [ [Daily Mail](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-11961673/Pub-landlord-centre-golliwogs-row-denies-hes-racist-White-Lives-Matter-posts.html) ]

> She confirmed that her husband had been photographed in a T-shirt from
> the far-right group Britain First. She said: “I don’t think Chris is a
> supporter of Britain First, he was just wearing that shirt because it
> was convenient at the time.”
>
> [The Guardian ]

Ce genre de déni par relativisation de l'histoire et de la discrimination et l'insistance à ne pas considérer l'impact des symboles, et de ses paroles, sur ses victimes, et à assimiler ces considérations au « politiquement correct », est typique de l'ignorance, du manque d'empathie, de l'insouciance ou de l'agenda d'une mouvance particulière.

Et doublement ici, puisque le terme « snowflake » peut référer à quelqu'un qui se croit unique ou qui fait la promotion du politiquement correct ou, historiquement, à quelqu'un « opposé à l'abolition de l'esclavage » ! ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/snowflake))

Pour rester dans le ton et souligner a contrario l'attitude des propriétaires, je suggère donc « plainte d'un [antiesclavagiste](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/antiesclavagiste) » ici. En fait, il s'agit simplement de la plainte de gens solidaires et conscients de l'impact de ce symbole sur une partie de la clientèle qu'on tente d'assimiler à la sensiblerie.

Comment: J'ajouterais possiblement « juste plainte ». L'étant fondamentalement mais la cooccurrence se prêtant aussi au sarcasme du « snowflake ».

Comment: Snowflake for anti-slavery is really old - not sure it's used a lot in that sense anymore, or would be readily understood as such, esp. in England. Using _snowflake_ in that sense IMHO, would be akin to resurrecting _scallywag_ which was used in the past in the US. The dominant meaning for _snowflake_ nowadays is more related to perceptions of entitlement, cancel culture, etc etc (in my opinion). Although in the context of this pub, the link to racism is hard to escape.

Comment: @Frank Agreed but it works in context, because that's the underlying topic which the owners want to be understated and subsumed to a gimmick. Incidentally, that's also what OP achieves at doing.

Comment: Vos commentaires sont intéressants en cela qu'ils éclairent le contexte, qui après tout semble être raciste. Cependant, ils ne répondent pas à la question : ce terme (« snowflake ») dépasse largement le contexte du racisme et de plus le racisme des propriétaires ne nous concerne pas ; le seul fait d'intérêt est leur communication, quelle qu'elle soit ; nous devons savoir ce qu'ils disent ; c'est au lecteur ensuite de juger de la valeur de leur propos.  (1/2)

Comment: Si ce qui peut être rendu par ce terme est « sensiblerie », il faudra juger les opinions de ceux qui l'utilisent selon le sens de ce mot, mais ça ne concerne pas le linguiste. La politique et le conflit social ne se discutent pas dans les réponses.  (2/2)

Comment: Généralement vrai, mais l'importance du sujet empêche d'en faire abstraction et la Q&A ne peut servir de moyen de l'évacuer, d'où ma réponse, néanmoins utile.

Comment: @s.H.a.R.p.R.i.F.t It does work in the context of that pub, I agree. A little strange though, because slavery/anti-slavery is a problematic more prominent in the US, IMHO, whereas this is a pub in England (Essex). Don't know how slavery/anti-slavery references/insults work in that British context today.

Comment: @Frank It seemingly works very well for the owners!

Comment: @s.H.a.R.p.R.i.F.t Yeah, I'm not disagreeing. I'm just saying, it would be a US bar in Alabama or Mississippi, it would be 100%. British pub - a bit surprising to me - but what do I know about slavery/anti-slavery and England...

Comment: https://www.bl.uk/restoration-18th-century-literature/articles/abolition-of-the-slave-trade-and-slavery-in-britain "White history month"!

Comment: @s.H.a.R.p.R.i.F.t Obviously not saying there was no slavery/anti-slavery issue in England. Just wondering how prominent of a theme it is today in politics/sociology. In comparison, it is still very "alive" in the US through the presence of a significant Black community with slave ancestry, discussions about reparations, etc etc.

Comment: @Frank I hear you. It is a valid point. Communications might make this less watertight than before. On the other hand, I [oppose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390708/1160200) safe spaces designed to cater to people who don't want to care. I will use any opportunity I get to make that point.

Answer (score 0):

As a yellow dog, woke, politically correct, Democrat (I try to be politically correct (imo=compassionate, considerate, open minded, [dare I say kind]), with woke=politically correct, no more, no less (btw, "yellow dog democrat"=l'd vote for the Democrat nominee even if he/she/it was a yellow (Labrador Retriever) Dog, who/which would obviously be more intelligent than any of my former republican (Tory, UMP, FN, whatever, (a POS by any other name, smells to high heaven) acquaintances.  Like Trump wearing his indictments as badges of honor, I will likewise, considering the likely source, wear the attempted insult of Snowflake.

If 'snowflake' is still recognized as meaning 'anti-slavery', it actually makes perfect sense i.e.: the current standard for determining if one is truly racist, is if one is pro-slavery (=racist) or anti-slavery (=non-racist). There's even AT LEAST one governor of one state who thinks that it's not racist to impose standards of learning on his state's MS collegians that include the absurd idea that slavery is/was beneficial to the enslaved. (Please consider boycotting Florida; it's terribly hot, humid, and, for the near future, governed by a racist bigot).

All that to say that 'Snowflake complaint' can be translated simply as:
'SNOWFLAKE'= "Sorry for no Gollys ... because of some [local] snowflake."

Comment: This is mostly a political stance; also the purely philosophical/political assertion "the current standard for determining …  (=non-racist). ", which can't but give rise to much controversy, is not a widely accepted fact; in my opinion you can be  fervently anti-slavery and still be racist (it is merely needed to reject the politics of interracial mixing, and you are a racist, but that does not mean that you necessarily consider that other races should be subjected to slavery).

Answer (score 0):

Comme Frank, je pense qu’une traduction qui prenne parfaitement en compte l’aspect *culture wars* est impossible.

Si l’on souhaite principalement conserver le caractère politique, on peut qualifier la personne de :

- "gauchiasse" (= *libtard* en anglais américain) : terme insultant désignant les personnes politiquement à gauche ;
- ["droit-de-l’hommiste"](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droit-de-l%27hommisme) : c’est-à-dire une personne prétendument attachée à des principes de liberté, mais qui les exploite de manière hypocrite pour parvenir à ses propres fins partisanes.

Dans les deux cas, l’usage de ce terme marque le locuteur comme (très ?) à droite.

Si l’on insiste plutôt sur la fragilité de la personne, le terme "chochotte" proposé par jlliagre est sans doute le meilleur. Une amélioration (?), si la personne visée est de genre masculin, serait le terme homophobe "tapette" (équivalent anglais : *faggot*), pour désigner un homme trop fragile. "Mauviette" est à peu près équivalent, sans l’homophobie, et peut s’appliquer à une femme.

Enfin, si l’on souhaite mettre en doute la légitimité de la plainte, l’équivalent bien français est ["tartufferie"](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tartufferie) (une affirmation hypocrite, digne du personnage [Tartuffe](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Tartuffe_ou_l%27Imposteur) de Molière). On pourrait aussi employer "pudeur de gazelle", une expression [inventée ou du moins popularisée en mars 2017 par Mélenchon](https://www.leparisien.fr/elections/presidentielle/pudeur-de-gazelle-on-est-remonte-aux-origines-de-l-expression-de-melenchon-21-03-2017-6782004.php), pour signifier une pudibonderie hors de propos. L’expression est toujours utilisée par la presse dans le domaine politique ([exemple en 2023 sur 20 minutes](https://www.20minutes.fr/politique/4024981-20230226-guerre-ukraine-an-apres-position-macron-fait-consensus-opposition)), et j’ai trouvé un usage hors du champ politique par [Le Point en 2019](https://www.lepoint.fr/societe/regles-la-pudeur-de-gazelle-de-la-television-appartient-elle-au-passe-12-10-2019-2340918_23.php).